# Gherkin Data Table using Node.js (and WebdriverIO)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, gherkin, webdriver-io

I want to implement a Gherkin step involving a data table in Node.js, but I'm not sure how the data should be passed in. Here is an example that I know works that does not utilize a data table.

**`test.feature`**

```
Feature: Testing login
  Scenario: Logging in with credentials
    When I login with credentials "user@example.com" and "p@ssw0rd"
```

**`login.js`**

```
import loginAsCreds from './loginAsCreds'

module.exports = function when () {
  this.When(
    /^I login as "(.+)" and "(.+)"/i,
      loginAsCreds
  )
```

**`loginAsCreds.js`**

```
module.exports = (email, password, done) => {
    browser.element('#email').keys(email)
    browser.element('#password').keys(password)
    browser.element('#signInButton').click()

    done()
}
```

Here is what I would like the feature file to look like.

**`test-desired.feature`**

```
Feature: Testing login
  Scenario: Logging in with credentials
    When I login with credentials:
      | user@example.com | p@ssw0rd |
```

I've tried a few things to modify `login.js` to pass the data table and `loginAsCreds.js` to accept it, but I am new to Node.js and WebdriverIO (but not Selenium or Gherkin). Could someone please point me in the right direction with this? Data tables would be very useful for other steps I plan to write, as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is the closest thing I've found, but because I want to define the function in another file, I think my lack of JS is getting in the way.

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/cukes/12av4y61em/cucumber-js-passing-arrays

Answer (score 0):

I had someone point me to the `cucumber js` documentation. I didn't know to search for that, so I found this page:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/9959ca9fd9f8c64f0b5133f9bb241da9b854e570/README.md

...which showed me I needed to add `.raw()` to my argument to access the data (since the table is a 2-D array), and points to this example:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/9959ca9fd9f8c64f0b5133f9bb241da9b854e570/features/data_tables.feature

This is what my code looks like now:

**test-desired.feature**

```
Feature: Testing login
  Scenario: Logging in with credentials
    When I login with credentials:
      | user@example.com | p@ssw0rd |
```

**login.js**

```
import loginAsCreds from './loginAsCreds'

module.exports = function when () {
  this.When(
    /^I login as:/i,
      loginAsCreds
  )
```

**loginAsCreds.js**

```
module.exports = (creds, done) => {
  email = creds.raw()[0][0]
  password = creds.raw()[0][1]

  browser.element('#email').keys(email)
  browser.element('#password').keys(password)
  browser.element('#signInButton').click()

  done()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the bitloops-gherkin package you are able to pull data from a Google Sheet and you can add any kind of format there which is then converted into Buffer data in the Gherkin table.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitloops-gherkin